# Create Contentfolders from APEX

Tags: apex, soap-api, metadata-api, contentdocument

Can someone please provide a sample code to create a contentfolder in a library using APEX? Do we still can't create folder without Metadata API?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to create contentfolder using the below code

```
ContentWorkspace cw = [SELECT Id, Name
                     FROM ContentWorkspace
                     WHERE Name = 'My Library'
                    ];
List < ContentFolderLink > cfl = [SELECT Id, ContentFolderId, ParentEntityId
                                 FROM ContentFolderLink
                                 WHERE ParentEntityId = : cw.Id
                                ];

if (cfl.size() > 0) {
 ContentFolder cf = new ContentFolder(Name = 'subfolder', ParentContentFolderId = cfl[0].ContentFolderId);
 Insert cf;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use RootContentFolderId field on ContentWorkspace object and define that value for the ParentContentFolderId field on the ContentFolder object.

[ContentWorkspace Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentworkspace.htm)

[ContentFolder Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentfolder.htm)

```
ContentWorkspace cw = [SELECT Id, Name, RootContentFolderId FROM ContentWorkspace WHERE Name = 'Library Name' LIMIT 1];

ContentFolder cf = new ContentFolder();
cf.Name = 'Folder Name';
cf.ParentContentFolderId = cw.RootContentFolderId;
insert cf;
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Thank you for contributing. NOTE: You do not have a `FROM` clause in your query statement. Please do a quick test of any code you post (especially as an answer) to ensure there are no typos and that it otherwise works as you intended. Further confusion could be caused if someone attempts to use non-tested code.

Comment: @Moonpie thanks for pointing that out. Edited!